# How can I set connection string of a stimulsoft report at run time on web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

I created a report in stimulsoft in asp.net c#. I created a new connection and then new data source, and added an exiting stored procedure to it. then I assigned columns and parameters this data source to my report.my problem is that :
when i create new sqlconnection manually the connection string is :

```
Data Source=my_pc-PC\my_servername;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=my database_name
```

when i run my site in my pc every thing is good an work. but when i set my site on web service do i do any thing to show my report successfully.
my code for run report:

```
 Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiText t = new Stimulsoft.Report.Components.StiText();
        t.Text = DateLabel.Text;
        string str4 = Decrypt(Request.QueryString["select_rep_"]);
        if (str4 == "1")
        {
            string str1 = Decrypt(Request.QueryString["fromdate_"]);
            string str2 = Decrypt(Request.QueryString["todate_"]);

            string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_ejraConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string serverlocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Empty);
            StiReport myreport = new StiReport();
            myreport.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary.StiSqlDatabase("Coneection", ConnectionString));
            t.Text = DateLabel.Text;
            myreport.Load(serverlocation + "\\rep\\myreport.mrt");
            myreport.Dictionary.Variables["fromdate"].Value = str1;
            myreport.Dictionary.Variables["todate"].Value = str2;
            myreport.Dictionary.Variables["today"].Value = t.Text;
            StiWebViewer1.Report = myreport;
        }`enter code here`
```

is this code work without any change on web server?

Comment: Check the connection string. Is it the same on the web service?

Do you get any error? Or there is just an empty Viewer? Do you see the Viewer?

Comment: hi thanks for reply. i dont deliver my site yet.i want know is my  code work without any change on web server?

Answer (score 0):

Do this, clear databases before use it :

```
myreport.Dictionary.Databases.Clear();

myreport.Dictionary.Databases.Add(new StiSqlDatabase("ConnectionName", "ConnectionString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Working to me, in `Asp.Net Core 2.0`

follow this code:

```
var myreport = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
_myreport.Load(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\report.mrt"); // load report file
((StiSqlDatabase)myreport.Dictionary.Databases["Connection"]).ConnectionString = "new ConnectionString"; // set new connection string
myreport.Render();
```

need to install NuGet Package `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore` version 2018.3.5

Hope to be useful.